# bootstrap 4 collapse opens the same card

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to hide the descriptions on each cards. In my code there is only one card because I use database with php to show them. The problem is, doesn't matter on which card I try to press the collapse button, it always opens the first one. I attach a gif so you can see the problem.
Here's my code:

```
<h5 class="card-description">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapse3">Heading 3</a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="card-body">
        <?php echo $record['description']; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</h5>
```

[a short video of the problem](https://i.gyazo.com/33d6edc167b3b3946766104bcd2f365c.mp4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because the link in the second card also refers to `#collapse3`.

Make sure to assign different ids to different elements. As in, inside one card, use ids such as `collapse1`, `headingOne`, etc. and for second card use `collapse2`, `headingTwo`, etc. But make sure that all your references are correct. As in check the `data-` and `aria-` tags as well.

In PHP:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading<?php echo $record['id'];?>">
<h5 class="mb-0">
    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $record['id'];?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $record['id'];?>">Heading 3</a>
</h5>
</div>
<div id="collapse<?php echo $record['id'];?>" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $record['id'];?>">
<div class="card-body">
    <?php echo $record['description'];?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how can I use different ids if I have only one card in my code? Should I use the ids from database?

Comment: how many cards are you planning to display? Just one or the cards will be pulled from the database?

Comment: A lot. They will be selected dfrom the database.

Comment: If you are planning to fetch the card data from the database, then you can use a for loop and name the ids as `collapse{index}` where index is the index of the for loop

Comment: Also not neccessary to use the same ids. you can use `heading1` instead of `headingOne`. So that it is easy for you to create it in the for loop. Just keep a check on the referencing. Make sure to change it to `heading1` everywhere

Comment: I'm using jquery - not sure if that's what you are askin tho.

Comment: I assumed that you are using PHP to display your content... Hence I used PHP syntax to display the cards...

Comment: I'm getting these errors: https://gyazo.com/7609ca6e1cb629a3c782b088e62b2d68

Comment: that for loop was just an example. Use the code in the for loop in which you are declaring the `$record` variable...

Comment: I just deleted the foreach line, and without that everything is working fine. Please edit your answer, and I'll accept it. Also thanks for your help.

Comment: wait, i'll make it more easier